# Dump database in sql format

Tags: c#, sqlite, dump

I am beginning to learn C# and a common third part .NET library System.Data.Sqlite

Here is a very simple code that I managed to write so far, based on online tutorials;

```
using System;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace SQLiteSamples
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=dummy.db");
            m_dbConnection.Open();
            string sql = "select * from my_table";
            SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
            SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                Console.WriteLine(reader["my_col"]);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to dump all database into an sql dump using utf8 encoding. Is this possbile using this library?

Comment: Can you give more information on what it is that you want?

Answer (score 0):

To select all tables in the database, use `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'`
You can then select from each table with `SELECT * FROM mytable`

You can then do something like DataTable.Load(reader) and then display each table with DataTable's methods.

Edit: To encode strings in utf 8 use

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(DataTable's output);
myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```